# Can I edit my Wishlist email notification settings with the Steam Client, instead of the website?

Tags: steam

Can I edit my Wishlist email notification settings with the Steam Client, instead of the website?

If so, how? I can't seem to access any email settings with the Steam Client?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [this article](https://gadgets.ndtv.com/games/features/how-to-enable-wishlist-notifications-in-steam-to-track-all-sales-706908), you can access the email notifications settings from the Steam Client by following these steps:

> 1. Switch on the Steam client. Log in to your account.
> 2. Click on your name on the top right. You'll see an option called Account details, click it.
> 3. This opens up your account within Steam's own browser, in the Contact Info section, you'll see an link called "Manage Email Preferences", click on it.
>      Configure your email preferences below it.